# PHP filter_input(): doesn't apply default value when $_GET["var"] is set but empty

Tags: php, filter, get

#### PHP filter_input() doesn't return its default value when the input is exist but empty

Let me assume that we have a page with this php code.

```
<?php

$keyword = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'keyword', FILTER_DEFAULT, array("options" => array(
    "default" => "default_value"
)));

echo $keyword;
```

1. When I open this page with this URL which has `keyword` param and a value;

http://example.com/?keyword=abc

It will return

```
abc
```

2. When I open the page with this URL which has **only `keyword` param**;

http://example.com/?keyword=

It will return

```
// nothing returned
```

I hoped `default_value` will be returned.

Do you know something about that?

Comment: You will need to resort to another method since that option doesn't seem to support empty values. The ternary operator here `echo $keyword = $keyword ? $keyword : "default_value";` would be a solution here.

Comment: Also, if you're looking if something is in an array, then use just that; `in_array()` along with the ternary operator and as suggested in the answer given below. Or, if GET `==` equals to something and not `empty()`. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: I made a wrap function of filter_input() with your suggestions and I'll use it with my own filter like FILTER_STRINGS_NOT_ALLOW_EMPTY. I think it's a better way for me. Thanks Fred -ii-.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `FILTER_DEFAULT` filter, no option is available (see `FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW` at http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php).

Otherwise `FILTER_DEFAULT` doesn't filter anything, so for your current case you'd better merely doing something like this:

```
$keyword = $_GET['keyword'] ? $_GET['keyword'] : 'default_value';
```

In the other hand, if you want to still use `filter_input()` another simple alternative for default is:

```
$keyword = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'keyword', FILTER_DEFAULT);
$keyword = $keyword ? $keyword : 'default_value';
```

Comment: Thanks cFreed. Umm. But even `filter_input()` with `FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW` is safer than your suggesting .
Is there any safer and simple tip?

Comment: @kujiy Didn't pay attention to the `STRIP` flags included when `FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW`, but I now understand why you prefer to still use `filter_input()`. So look at my edited answer.

Comment: @cFreed A ternary would be the way to go for sure.

Comment: @cFreed I understand. I'm going to use both `filter_input()` and the `ternary`. Thank you so much. I made a wrap function of `filter_input()` with your suggestions and I'll use it with my own filter like `FILTER_STRINGS_NOT_ALLOW_EMPTY`. I think it's a better way for me.

Comment: @kujiy Glad to help. And BTW you're perfectly right: to encapsulate what matches your need once you clearly identified it is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that only `keyword` is used as a filter, therefore it's not going to show you anything else.

Had `keyword=` been in its place, it would have shown you the default value.

Therefore, you're probably best to use a ternary operator and check if the GET array is empty.

A partial solution to this, and using your present code would be and using a conditional `!empty()` (NOT EMPTY):

```
<?php

$keyword = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'keyword', FILTER_DEFAULT, array("options" => array(
    "default" => "default_value"
)));

if(!empty($keyword)){

   echo $keyword;

}

else{

   echo "The array is empty.";

}
```

or as a ternary operator:

```
<?php

$keyword = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'keyword', FILTER_DEFAULT, array("options" => array(
    "default" => "default_value"
)));

echo $keyword = $keyword ? $keyword : "default_value";
```

Sidenote: `echo $keyword = ...` is valid syntax. It both echo's and assigns at the same time.

Comment: Hi Fred -ii-. Thank you for your advice. I understand. I'm going to use both `filter_input()` and the `ternary`. Thank you so much.

Comment: @kujiy You're most welcome. Glad to have been of help and that you found your final solution, *cheers!*